# Get all redundant elements via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, dtd

How can I get all the elements that have appeared more than once via XPath?

```
<!DOCTYPE book [
<!ELEMENT book (title,section+)>
<!ELEMENT chapter (title,body?,section*)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST chapter number ID CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
```

I need all the `title` elements that have appeared more than once.

Comment: can you post an example of the data?

Comment: I do not have any example of the data @Daniele

Comment: @NickyMirfallah, can you use XPath 2.0 or XSLT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can for example search for a `title` that's identical for a title following it:

```
//title[.=following::title]
```

Comment: If this is intended to select all `title` elements that appear more than once in the document, it will miss the last `title`; if it's intended to omit the last `title` because it's already been selected, then it ought to also omit the other `titles` that have already been selected.   As it is, I think it's a mix of two possibilities that probably ought to be separated.  I explain further [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35834422/290085).

Answer (score 1):

### XPath 1.0 Solution <sub><sup>(also works with XPath 2.0)</sup></sub>

1. If you want all `title` elements that appear more than once, you can use this XPath 1.0 expression:

   ```
   //title[.=following::title or .= preceding::title]
   ```
2. If you'd like to select a set (with no duplicates) of all `title` elements that appear more than once in the document, you can use this XPath 1.0 expression:

   ```
   //title[.=following::title][not(. = preceding::title)]
   ```

To see the difference, consider this XML (not valid per your DTD, but still helpful as an example):

```
<r>
  <title>a</title>
  <title>b</title>
  <title>c</title>
  <title>a</title>
  <title>a</title>
  <title>b</title>
  <title>b</title>
  <title>b</title>
</r>
```

XPath #1 selects:

```
<title>a</title>
<title>b</title>
<title>a</title>
<title>a</title>
<title>b</title>
<title>b</title>
<title>b</title>
```

(all `title` elements in the example except for the `c` `title`)

XPath #2 selects:

```
<title>a</title>
<title>b</title>
```

Either might serve your purposes, depending upon exactly what you need to do with the results.